# How to define a sound in my project as ringtone and notification?

Tags: java, android, audio, buffer

I have done an apk that play sounds (*.ogg) and now I need to know how to set then as ringtone and notification, I already done a menu and buttons where I can obtain the name of the sound to define, they are inside de apk project in res/raw folder... I have no ideia of how to do that...

Thanks guys =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a sound file in `res/raw`, you can get the `Uri` for it like this:

```
Uri ringtone = Uri.parse("android.resource://{package}/{resource_id}");
```

Then, with the `Uri`, you can play the ringtone like this:

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
mp.setDataSource(ringtone.getPath());
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Comment: what would be the "{resource_id}"?  the name of the ogg file?

Comment: The resource ID is an `int` which uniquely identifies a resource in your application's `R.java` file. For example, `R.raw.myfile` will give you the resource ID for the file `myfile` stored in `res/raw`.